# How do I make Cedilla (ç) character available in English USA?

Tags: 11.04, special-characters

I need the character Cedilla working my English USA Ubuntu Natty but when use the normal combination ' then c I get this ć. In the previous versions I used this solution: [[SOLVED] Getting ç cedilla instead of c acute with american keyboards](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1330912) but it isn't working on Natty. Any help will be very appreciatted! Best regards.

Comment: Did you try `gksudo gedit /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/gtk.immodules`

Answer (score 9):

Bug reference: [#518056](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/518056)

Answer from [Hélio José](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/518056/comments/39):

For 64-bit systems:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache
sudo -H gedit /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache
```

For 32-bit systems:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache
```

Change the line

```
"cedilla" "Cedilla" "gtk20" "/usr/share/locale" "az:ca:co:fr:gv:oc:pt:sq:tr:wa"
```

to

```
"cedilla" "Cedilla" "gtk20" "/usr/share/locale" "az:ca:co:fr:gv:oc:pt:sq:tr:wa:en"
```

Replace "ć" with "ç" and "Ć" with "Ç" in `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`

```
sudo cp /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose.bak
sed 's/ć/ç/g' < /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose | sed 's/Ć/Ç/g' > Compose
sudo mv Compose /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose
```

Add two lines in `/etc/environment`

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla
```

Restart your computer.

Comment: the step 3 is the only needed for the most recent ubuntu releases - 13.10 and 14.04

Answer (score 3):

Choose keyboard = USA international with dead keys

Try Keyboard>layout>options>Key to choose 3rd level> right ctrl

then try **right ctrl** +  **<**, press first the **right ctrl** and keep it pressed, then

with another finger press **<**

Comment: by default this behavior in any other setting is of right alt (aka AltGr). Thus, there's no need to change this setting and instead you can simply use AltGr + comma

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a hurry, do this and you'll get "ç" instead of "ć":

Press "AltGr + ," then "c".

If you want to know a bit more, keep on reading.

This may be solved already by using one of the answers above, but I realized the best thing to do is use the keyboard layout, instead of changing things you'll have to eventually change again in the future (after updates, for example).

Before I start, keep in mind I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2, which is not the same distro as the original question mentions (11.04). Anyway, I believe most users migrated to newwer versions by now. So:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

Okay, the first thing I did was looking at the immodules files:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache

At the header, those files clearly mention they should not be changed, since they're generated automatically:

```
# GTK+ Input Method Modules file
# Automatically generated file, do not edit
# Created by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 from gtk+-3.10.8
```

So changing them, although it may solve the problem temporarily, is not ideal.

Looking around, I found the best answer ever about why we get a "ć" instead of a "ç" when typing ' + c: because we're really putting an acute accent on the top of letter "c". So the layout is right. With that in mind, how would one put a "kind of a" comma at the bottom of the "c" letter? Using a comma, of course!

So, the solution was the key combination AltGR + , and then "c".

No need for changing any configuration on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **Character Map** you can copy and paste the character.

[image: Character Map: Ced]

Answer (score 0):

Use ibus to provide you with these special characters. You will need to install the compose extension to ibus from the software centre or synaptic.