# How to type "ç" when using USA intl as the keyboard layout?

Tags: unity, gnome, keyboard-layout

I asked [the same question when I used Maverick Meerkat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14202/how-to-use-an-input-language-different-from-the-keyboard-layout-country-and-from) but I can't make that solutions work on Unity. I want to use the keys <kbd>´</kbd> followed by <kbd>c</kbd> and the output should be "ç". It works that way in Windows out of the box, and it did work in Ubuntu 10.10 following the solutions given in the question above. But in 11.04 it outputs "ć". How to change that?

Comment: We're searching for a solution here but we should really be asking ourselves why this behaviour in the first place. Windows and Mac behave as expected for `us intl` layout: `' + c = ç`. Why going through all this suffering and misery for so many years on linux systems?

Comment: like this: ç  ... jkjk

Comment: If any of you installed FCITX, maybe [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1499993/195881) might be of help. I think FCITX undoes the previous configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit `/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/gtk.immodules` 
Modify the line where you can find "cedilla" add ":en" at the end

`"cedilla" "Cedilla" "gtk20" "/usr/share/locale" "az:ca:co:fr:gv:oc:pt:sq:tr:wa:en"`

Edit `/etc/environment`
Add: `export GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla`

---

**Edit** for **Ubuntu 12.10**: (according to [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/216034/47206) by [Hoerlle](https://askubuntu.com/users/36509/hoerlle))

the `gtk.immodule` file is located at:

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/gtk.immodules`

or

`/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/gtk.immodules`

---

For KDE and other applications that are not GTK:
Edit: `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose`

Find all ocorrencies for ć and replace it all for ç, remember to look for the the uppercase matches too Ć and Ç

You may need to restart your gnome.

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu 13.10, I fixed it by adding the following  lines in `/etc/environment`:

```
GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla 
QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla
```

Comment: For me, in Ubuntu 13.10 and Gnome Shell, worked too.

Comment: It worked too in Mint 18

Comment: It didn´t work on NixOS.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the **Dvorak International layout with dead keys**;there's a good possibility that QWERT International with dead keys also uses these keys. On mine, the comma is a live key. (It's used often enough that it would be annoying if it were a dead key.)

For a ç. try <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (right <kbd>Alt</kbd>) + <kbd>,</kbd>. For a capital, Ç, try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>.

Comment: using Dvorak might be more annoying than a dead comma key for people that are used with QWERT

Answer (score 2):

Using the same answer for the same question found here: [How do I make Cedilla (ç) character available in English USA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39837/how-do-i-make-cedilla-%C3%A7-character-available-in-english-usa/599537#599537)

If you're in a hurry, do this and you'll get "ç" instead of "ć":

Press "AltGr + ," then "c".

If you want to know a bit more, keep on reading.

This may be solved already by using one of the answers above, but I realized the best thing to do is to use the keyboard layout, instead of changing things you'll have to eventually change again in the future (after updates, for example).

Before I start, keep in mind I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.2, which is not the same distro as the original question mentions (11.04). Anyway, I believe most users have already migrated to newer versions by now. So:

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

Okay, the first thing I did was looking at the immodules files:

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache

At the header, those files clearly mention they should not be changed, since they're generated automatically:

```
# GTK+ Input Method Modules file
# Automatically generated file, do not edit
# Created by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3-0/gtk-query-immodules-3.0 from gtk+-3.10.8
```

So changing them, although it may solve the problem temporarily, is not ideal.

Looking around, I found the best answer ever about why we get a "ć" instead of a "ç" when typing ' + c: because we're really putting an acute accent on the top of letter "c". So the layout is right. With that in mind, how would one put a "kind of a" comma at the bottom of the letter "c"? Using a comma, of course!

So, the solution was the key combination AltGR + , and then "c".

No need for changing any configuration on your computer.

Comment: NixOS here, it shows this to me: ©  

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 12.10 the `gtk.immodules` file to be edited are located at:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/gtk.immodules
```

or

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/gtk.immodules
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the accent, not the apostrophe:

accent + c (´+c) = ç trencada

Comment: I was using the accent <kbd>´</kbd> all the time, but the question didn't reflect it, so I edited the question, invalidating your answer. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

In Xfce 12.10 I have solved it by **installing `ibus` package and its dependencies**.

This is [a bug reported here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/518056) (and the [solution is mentioned in a comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/518056/comments/11) - more specifically [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/518056/comments/15).)

Answer (score 0):

In Kubuntu 15.04, after replacing cedillas for the  /usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose as described by others above, only qt-based apps were OK. After that, I installed ibus-gtk and ibus-gtk3 and it fixed my problem to firefox and other gtk-based apps as well.

Answer (score 0):

First find the key that is used to type accents just like this *é, è, á, à*. (Normally it's in the same line as the numbers)

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Gr</kbd> and that key at the same time. When finished this, press <kbd>C</kbd> (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, if you want a capital cedilla: *Ç* like this).

Answer (score 0):

[Same answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1683563/1596205). Repeated below for convenience.

---

I have created a simple bash script following @ThoriumBR answer. This way, whenever there's an update to your system and you'll lose that config, you can just run the script again.

The script is idempotent, so feel free to run as many time as you want, the result won't change.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Setting vars up
COMPOSE_FILE='/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose'
GTK2_FILE='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules.cache'
GTK3_FILE='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules.cache'
ENV_FILE='/etc/environment'

# Backing up files
sudo cp ${COMPOSE_FILE} ${COMPOSE_FILE}.bak
sudo cp ${GTK2_FILE} ${GTK2_FILE}.bak
sudo cp ${GTK3_FILE} ${GTK3_FILE}.bak

# Fixing cedilla in Compose
sudo sed --in-place -e 's/ć/ç/g' ${COMPOSE_FILE}
sudo sed --in-place -e 's/Ć/Ç/g' ${COMPOSE_FILE}

# Fixing cedilla in GTK files
GTK_FILE_SEARCH_FOR='^"cedilla".*:en'
GTK_FILE_SED_EXP='s/^\(\"cedilla\".*:wa\)/\1:en/g'

grep -q ${GTK_FILE_SEARCH_FOR} ${GTK2_FILE}
[ $? -eq 1 ] && sudo sed --in-place -e ${GTK_FILE_SED_EXP} ${GTK2_FILE}
grep -q ${GTK_FILE_SEARCH_FOR} ${GTK3_FILE}
[ $? -eq 1 ] && sudo sed --in-place -e ${GTK_FILE_SED_EXP} ${GTK3_FILE}

# Fixing cedilla in environment file
ENV_FILE_GTK_LINE='GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla'
ENV_FILE_QT_LINE='QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla'

grep -q ${ENV_FILE_GTK_LINE} ${ENV_FILE}
[ $? -eq 1 ] && echo ${ENV_FILE_GTK_LINE} | sudo tee -a ${ENV_FILE} > /dev/null
grep -q ${ENV_FILE_QT_LINE} ${ENV_FILE}
[ $? -eq 1 ] && echo ${ENV_FILE_QT_LINE} | sudo tee -a ${ENV_FILE} > /dev/null
```

Then you can save it to a file such as `fix-cedilla.sh` and run it with `bash fix-cedilla.sh`. Or you can mark that file as executable with `chmod +x fix-cedilla.sh` and run it with `./fix-cedilla.sh`.

You can/should also add it to your dotfiles repo ([example of mine](https://github.com/lfilho/dotfiles/blob/main/bin/fix-cedilla-in-linux.sh)) so next time you (re)install your OS it's handy in a known place ;-)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
If all you want is to change the ç and not the others consonant accented keys that comes with US-international layout from Linux:

1. Create a file named .XCompose
2. Put in the beginning of the file **include "%L"** this will import the original configuration of **/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose**
3. Then add those lines :

> < dead_acute>< C> : "Ç"
>
> < dead_acute>< c> : "ç" **without the spaces inside the < >**

4. Save your file in **~/** directory
5. Reboot

===========================================================================

**But if you want your keyboard act like US-international from Windows :**

For everyone that wanted that US-international keyboard like Windows.
There is a github repo that can make this work: https://github.com/raelgc/win_us_intl Here what you want to do:

1. download the zip file
2. extract wherever you want, your focus should be on the **XCompose** file.
3. Open the XCompose file with your preferred text editor, and then put bellow **include "/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"** a line like this: **include "%L"**
4. Move the XCompose file to the **~/** directory
5. Reboot

Comment: Some of those steps have bad side effects, and don't really contribute to the solution. So I downvoted; sorry.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson could you please tell me what are those bad side effects ? Also the user wanted his US-international keyboard behave just like Windows out of the box, and with these steps you can achieve it. export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" is for the .XCompose file to be readed, and IBus take precedence over some applications keyboard shortcuts, so you would have to redefine key combinations on both side to avoid such effects

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Anyway I edited the post, could you check now if it's a good solution ? Because it works wonderful for me, like before I did this steps if i hit " 'm" for exemple it would show me an accented m, and it was like this for every consonant letter.

Comment: Gtk reads `~/.XCompose` - you don't need to enable XIM for that. XIM is an old method with issues, and especially the en_US.UTF-8 Compose file is huge and might affect performance adversely. As regards IBus it may have some effect on shortcuts, but please note that IBus is installed by default in standard Ubuntu. And if you tell im-config to not start it, GNOME will start it and configure the important variables anyway.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson  Ohh I see, well sorry I didn't know about this, I was just doing some steps that I found searching on the internet. I edited the post.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Gunnar I did the test in my machine and without setting GTK_IM_MODULE="xim" it won't work, gtk is not reading my .XCompose file, could you tell me another method so that I can make gtk reads XCompose ? I already tried these steps: on .profile set export GTK_IM_MODULE="gtk-im-context-simple", tried to kill ibus, tried to restart ibus, tried with uim and tried to remove run_im ibus from .xinputrc.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Can you also tell me what are those issues with the XIM method ? Because It seems to be my only solution to the problem of reading XCompose file.

Comment: "The internet" is loaded with dubious and obsolete advice. Gtk reads `~/.XCompose` fine for me without modifying `GTK_IM_MODULE` or enabling XIM. I'd be willing to talk more, but in that case I'd suggest that you ask a new question. As regards issues with XIM, [this bug report](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1573755) may give you an idea.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I asked a new question, here is the link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228549/my-system-isnt-reading-the-xcompose-file