# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: "Cedilha"

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, special-characters

I am a beginner and I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with text entry given by English International with dead keys.

Everything works well but instead of getting "ç" I get "ć".

Yes, the key that I have in my keyboard is apostrophe and not accent.

I have found some solutions in [How to type cedilha](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59663/how-to-type-%C3%A7-when-using-usa-intl-as-the-keyboard-layout), but they assume that you are able to find a file /usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/gtk.immodules, but I am not able to do that.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about that file you mentioned, but as you will not need this special c very often I suppose, maybe using the screen keyboard would be enough? I think it's called onboard. You should reach it in the panel with that round symbol with a human inside. At least you could work with this until you find a real solution.

Comment: Thank you! This can be one solution! +1. I didnt know about that.

Comment: Many people hate reading all these "Thank you" "+1" etc comments, because they provide no useful information and just occupy space. I don't care, but next time maybe just voting or accepting the answer is better. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I think this is a way to deal with the problem, but unfortunatelly it is not an actual solution. A solution is to change the system in order to make it run correctly. It seems there is this kind of solution for other versions of Ubuntu, but I am not able to that for this version!

Answer (score 1):

I use the "English (International AltGr dead keys)" layout, I've found it easier for entering the characters I need. Using the right Alt key as AltGr, AltGr+vowels gives me accents, AltGr+< gives me the cedilla (ç). It's not exactly "dead keys" as there's no "standby accent" but it works.

Comment: Thank you! However, it does not work on my computer.