# FCITX and Cedilla Conflicting Configurations

Tags: input-method, japanese, chinese, fcitx, korean

I'm a Brazilian Portuguese native speaker, and, as such, I'm in need of the `ç`, not `ć` — which I believe is used in way less popular languages, so why is it the default??? —, so, in the past, I've followed tutorials like these, in order to override this behavior:

- [Ask Ubuntu - How to type latin small letter c with cedilla](https://askubuntu.com/a/402196/195881)
- [@nilo's Gist on How to Configure the Cedilla](https://gist.github.com/nilo/c2a31a0f9f29c88145ca)
- [My Notes on How to Configure Cedilla on Artix](https://github.com/psygo/dotfiles_artix/blob/master/.notes/cedilla.md)

Recently, I've restarted learning Korean, and so I installed [FCITX](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fcitx5) to have an *input method* for their different symbols. However, in FCITX's configuration, it is recommended/required for you to add this to your environment:

```sh
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export SDL_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
```

which conflicts with the last step in the above mentioned cedilla configuration of:

```sh
export GTK_IM_MODULE=cedilla
export QT_IM_MODULE=cedilla
```

How am I supposed to work around this? Is there a way of overriding FCITX only for cedilla somehow? I think that would probably be the easiest method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the process twice once again, this time it's working for some reason.

I suspect FCITX undid my previous configuration, and maybe the files I needed to change again get updated sequentially. I really don't know.

Update: I think this happens every time a core update happens (Arch Linux).